# Dependency Injection - Using a static dependency field instead of injecting to each object

Tags: c#, design-patterns, dependency-injection

What is wrong with having the dependency object as a static field in a static class instead of injecting it to each object that depends on it through constructor?

```
public static class Dependencies
{
    public static IUsersRepository Users;
    ...
}
//Use in a method that depends on Users Repository
var users = Dependencies.Users.GetUsers();
```

VS.

```
public class UserController
{
    private IUsersRepository _users;
    public UserController(IUsersRepository repo)
    {
        this._users = repo;
    }
    public List<User> GetCustomUsers()
    {
        var users = this._users.GetUsers();
        ...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To be honest, the police aren't going to come knocking on your door if you do, but taken to it's logical conclusion (i.e. an application of any appreciable size) you end up with a more difficult to maintain "spaghetti code" codebase.

Mostly, coupling, and things like the [SOLID principles](http://butunclebob.com/ArticleS.UncleBob.PrinciplesOfOod). You are tightly coupling to the `Dependency` class, when ideally DI prevents this by building object graphs for you, injecting the dependencies, so those objects have no knowledge (i.e. are not coupled) to the implementation that provides them. If you're using a DI container and a singleton lifestyle, then you've essentially got what you describe - static fields. But with a container (even the "containerless" style containers that are becoming popular) you get more flexibility and the hard things are done for you.

There are a few cases where using DI, particularly via a container, are probably a bad idea (logging, generating new Guid values, getting the current date). You can solve those few cases with the "ambient context" solution (see [Matthew Watson's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38348894/26414) for more details).

Answer (score 4):

There is a DI pattern called "Ambient Context" you can use to do this.

It allows you to avoid passing a cross-cutting concern all the time, but it still allows you to Unit Test things.

The canonical example is a DateTime provider:

```
public abstract class TimeProvider {
   private static TimeProvider current =
   DefaultTimeProvider.Instance;

   public static TimeProvider Current {
      get { return TimeProvider.current; }
      set {
         if (value == null) {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("value");
         }
         TimeProvider.current = value;
      }
   }

   public abstract DateTime UtcNow { get; }

   public static void ResetToDefault() {
      TimeProvider.current = DefaultTimeProvider.Instance;
   }
}
```

Where an implementation might look like this:

```
public class DefaultTimeProvider : TimeProvider {
   private readonly static DefaultTimeProvider instance = 
      new DefaultTimeProvider();

   private DefaultTimeProvider() { }

   public override DateTime UtcNow {
      get { return DateTime.UtcNow; }
   }

   public static DefaultTimeProvider Instance {
      get { return DefaultTimeProvider.instance; }
   }
}
```

Code would use `TimeProvider.Current` to access the DateTime rather than using `DateTime` directly.

The default concrete implementation returns the usual DateTime.UtcNow. However, for unit testing you can use a special test implementation and set `TimeProvider.Current` to it before running the unit tests.

[See this page (where that code comes from) for more information.](https://relentlessdevelopment.wordpress.com/2013/09/30/testing-datetimes-and-other-things-with-an-ambient-context/)

Note that you should only use this pattern for truly cross-cutting concerns such as DateTime, security, logging and so on.

Comment: +1 for the Ambient Context pattern, though, it is a particular solution to the problem. I asked about problems with static dependency approach.

Answer (score 2):

Suppose that a `UserController` would like to use an instant `IUsersRepository` and another `UserController` would like to use an instance of a different `IUserRepository` implementation, then you can't do this with static dependencies.

Comment: Assuming that all UserController s will use only a signle instance of IUsersRepository, are there still problems with static dependency approach ?

Comment: No, and you don't break dependency injection with injecting through fields/properties. However, it is still better to construct an object with fixed dependencies than expecting that the object dependencies might change anytime during its lifetime.